# Executing a transaction keeps failing after confirmation by owners

Tags: gnosis, gnosis-safe

I setup a 2/3 multisigwallet to interact with ERC1155 contract i created on rinkeby network. After confirmation by 2 owners of this multisigwallet. The execution keeps failing. I also tried to execute this transaction using the actual owner of the contract but the transactions also failed. When i interact with the contract on rinkeby.etherscan.io everything works fine but fails when i use gnosis safe. This is the webpage of the multisig https://gnosis-safe.io/app/rin:0x2C015eA5fB2Eb9a9c893090c873C9546bb7e1D18/transactions/queue and this is the contract execution that keeps failing https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x635a7a45ddcadff48ad31f8fccce0bae5d57e317a4180ac10712bb30e00b6db1

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase gas limit. Looks like this transaction fails beacause of lack of gas.

For test try to execute transaction with 1m gas or more.

Comment: yes it seems that the Ethereum tx has a gaslimit of 61k which is way too low for a tx that interacts with a Safe.

I would recommend to use `eth_estimateGas`